What is the complete sentence of “Shame on you”?
What is the complete sentence of “Shame on you”?
“Shame” looks like a noun to me. There is no verb in the sentence. Could native speakers please explain it to me? Thank you.

In exclamations there is often an implicit BE.   Good for you! Shame on you! Way to go! Wonderful!

The meaning is, "You should feel shame for what you did" or "I hope this brings shame to you." Idioms often don't follow the normal grammar rules. I'm sure it's a pain for someone trying to learn English, but you just have to memorize them.

It is a complete utterance and has idiomatic meaning.
It could be understood to have developed from the sense "Reproach incurred or suffered; dishonour; ignominy; derision" (wiktionary) and the "full sentence" would be "There is shame on you".  But a native speaker would not think of "Shame on you" as being the shortened form of anything, but a complete idiom.
Shame is a noun in this idiom.
You might compare this with expressions like "Good on you" or "(More) power to your elbow".

You're right, "shame" is a noun but in this context, "shame" is a verb. The phrase "on you" is a prepositional phrase indicating the person or entity that is being shamed.

No, it's a noun. "May shame be upon you".

-1 No. "Shame" as a verb is transitive. There's no object in "Shame on you".
